# Full-bridge rectifier is not working

Tags: high-voltage, bridge-rectifier, full-bridge

I tried to copy the full-bridge rectifier circuit diagram but for some reason it's not working. I think the current is not flowing from the high-voltage circuit device because I tried to hook up a pair of gator clippers on the red cable ends and it's not giving me an arc.

[image]

I'd post the full bridge rectifier circuit diagram but I'm only allowed to post one picture.

Comment: Nice book lousy background for your bridge. Please redo it on a plain background. Try using either a multi meter to measure the voltage, sparks are very unreliably useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in the assembly of the bridge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKcwjG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematics above, the diodes are oriented always exactly as in the picture. The connections of C1, HV input, and spark gap output are changed as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: I changed the position of the capacitor and resoldered it and it still doesn't work...

Comment: (@peteblank the main change is source connected to the A-K nodes, out K-K to A-A.)

Comment: Well thank you I guess.

Comment: @peteblank Look carefully. Everything but the diodes has moved!